# Radial tilings with variable area ratios

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, tiling

I was looking at this neat page on logarithmic spiral tilings when a question popped up:

http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/symmetry/log-spir.htm

It seems that in all of the tilings shown, the area of each tile is exponentially increasing as a function of the distance to the origin.  Are there any radial- or spiral-type tilings (or "tiling-like" configurations) in which the area of each tile is a *polynomial* function of the distance to the origin, say $r^{1/2}$ or $r^2$?  I don't require similarity of shapes or anything, just a simple way to fill the plane with shapes possessing (or approximately possessing) this property.  I guess it would be nice if the shapes stay reasonable rounded and convex (i.e. not really long and skinny).

Comment: Obviously, one can do a tiling with parallelograms (or triangle, or anything one can make a parallelogram from) and any rate of growth. But I do not see any other shapes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Grunbaum and Shephard book cover]
See Section 9.5, "Spiral Tilings," p.512ff.
These remarkable tilings go back to H. Voderberg in the 1930's.

Comment: In these tilings the size does not grow...

Comment: Yes, my point was that exponential growth in the OP's examples is not essential.  And I guess $f(r)=1$ is technically polynomial growth! :-)

Comment: No, $f(r)=\exp(cr)$ with $c=0$ is exponential growth :)

Comment: @Piero: Ha! Touché!

Comment: The cover of this book is frequently mistaken as a Voderberg tiling. In fact, it it not. The Voderberg tile is shown clearly in Fig. 3.2.4 and the tiling is in Fig. 9.5.1.