# Graphs determined by monohedral, edge-to-edge tilings of the plane

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry, tiling, planar-graphs

Let $\cal T$ be a monohedral, edge-to-edge tiling of the plane, with prototile $T$ a simple polygon, and with one edge $e^*$ of $T$ distinguished. Associate a graph $G=G_{\cal T}$ with $\cal T$ as follows. Each copy $T_i$ of $T$ in $\cal T$ is a node of $G$, and $T_1$ and $T_2$ are connected by an arc in $G$ if they share a distinguished edge of either tile.

$G$ is a planar graph without isolated nodes, often disconnected, and without loops as @DimaPasechnik observed. Note that $G$ depends on both $T$ and $e^*$:

---

[image: PentagonTiling]

          

<sup>Distinguished edges marked red.</sup>

          

<sup>Top: $G =$ collection of $4$-cycles. Bottom: $G =$ collection of segments.</sup>

---

My question is: Which graphs $G_{\cal T}$ can be realized by some tiling $\cal T$. Because there seems to be considerable freedom to "design" $G$ when $T$ is a regular $\{3,4,6\}$-gon, or tiles with several equal-length edges (such as polyominoes<sup>1</sup>), perhaps this is an easier question:

> ***Q***. What are some graphs $G$ that cannot be realized by some tiling $\cal T$?

*Added*. An example where choosing the "base" of the horn-shape as the distinguished edge, seems to produce an infinite chain.

---

[image: SpiralTiling]

          

<sup>Image: [An introduction to tilings](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2008-2009/KathrynLindsey/PROJECT/homepage.html). J.O'Rourke mods.</sup>

          

<sup>Original MO: [Radial tilings with variable area ratios](https://mathoverflow.net/a/83148/6094)
.
Grünbaum & Shephard.</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>
Rhoads, Glenn C. "Planar tilings by polyominoes, polyhexes, and polyiamonds." *Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics* 174, no. 2 (2005): 329-353.
[Journal link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042704002195).

Comment: can such a graph have loops?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: Under my definition, there can be no loop, for then the tile would have to join with itself along a distinguished edge, and the tile would then not be a simple polygon. So that's a good point: No loops. Thanks!

Comment: it is tempting to say that all you can get is a collection of cycles and isolated edges.

Comment: An edge between two vertices has to come from a copy of $e^*$ in one of the corresponding tiles. So any finite set of $n$ vertices can span at most $n$ edges, and consequently all you can get are disjoint unions of trees and unicyclic graphs (giving plenty of graphs that cannot be realised).

Comment: @FlorianLehner: Thanks, that observation nearly characterizes the graphs. Thanks!